# Is it important that every TLS1.2 encrypted message have padding?

Tags: tls, pkcs7

what if data we are sending is such that

**size(data) + size(mac)  =multiple of block size**

If this case if possible how the receiver will determine that no padding is present
???

Answer (score 2):

When the size of the data and mac is equal to a multiple of the block size, a complete block of padding is added. So in effect, there no TLS message that is not padded.

Comment: +1 for the succinct answer.  If no padding was added in cases where the data+mac is equal to a multiple of the block size, then there would be no way for the recipient to distinguish this case from a padding error.